# Can a pivot query be used on a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7292/2)

I was wondering if its possible to use a pivot on a single table inorder to display all the parents and their children in the same record? Results would look something like this:
[image] A child is someone who has a ParentID and a parent is someone who does not.

Comment: For a PIVOT you need to know the number of columns in advance - they can't appear dynamically.  I'm not sure this would work for an arbitrarily deep hierarchy.

Comment: What do you need the data in this format for - there may be a better way to do it?

Comment: You're aware that biology dictates *two* parents, not just one?  And law can make that more complex?

Comment: This is just an example, I'm not interested in the Biology.